# romove last 5 character of string in Unix

Tags: dos2unix

I need to trim last 8 character of a file name
Example:

```
Input -Vignesh.dat12345678
expected o/p : Vignesh.dat
```

I tried using rev but it didn't worked.

Comment: Give us your code...

Answer (score 0):

Your question says that you need to remove 5 characters, while the description says 8 !!!

Standard Format-

`echo Vignesh.dat12345678 | rev | cut -c X- | rev`

Assuming you want to remove 8 characters,

`echo Vignesh.dat12345678 | rev | cut -c 9- | rev`

The above code will remove last 8 characters. To remove `n` characters, simply put `(n+1)` instead of `X`.